# Tangent line of a function in 1st quadrant forms a triangle. Find the Area.

Tags: calculus

So, i have this particular question, that is Calculus based.
Here is the question below:

> > Consider graph of $f(x) = \exp(-x)$, for $x \geq 0$ . The tangent line to the graph of $f(x)$ at $x = a$, and intersects the $x$-axis at point $A$, and the $y$-axis at point $B$. Determine the area of triangle $AOB$ in terms of $a$.

Hence the coordinate on the $x$-axis is $(A,0)$ and coordinate on the $y$-axis is $(0,B)$.

I did some work on this.
The slope of the tangent line would be : $m = -\exp(-a)$
So my equation of the tangent line would be : $y = [-\exp(-a)]x + B$,
next i plug in the point : $(A,0)$
Then get the relation $B = A\exp(-a)$, therefore the full equation of the tangent line is:
$y = -\exp(-a)[x-A]$

Now the area is of a right triangle with vertices $AOB$,
that area is :
Area = $AB/2.$
Plugging in the relation of $B = A\exp(-a)$.
Then Area = $[(A^2)\exp(-a)]/2$

BUT my formula depends on the $x$-axis coordinate $A$.
SO not sure if this $A$ can be replace with it being related to '$a$', the point of tangent.

Hope some one can give some input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. $y=-e^{-a}(x-A)$  However at $x=a$ we have $y=e^{-a}$.  Therefore $a-A=-1$ or $A=a+1$.

Comment: Hi Herb, thanks for this. I can't believe i did not see this. But when i plug into the line equation i get slightly different than you i get : A = a -1. But i will award this question to you! You basically guided me all the way there. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, I just saw i made the mistake, i forgot the negative sign in my own equation. SO you were correct Herb. Thanks once more.

Comment: I saw a typo, which I corrected.  I had omitted the = sign for the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

As the point of tangency also lies on the tangent line, the point $(a, \exp(-a))$ too lies on $y = -\exp(-a)[x-A]$